# One-to-one relationship. Parent keeps reference of deleted child

Tags: jdo, datanucleus, one-to-one

I'm working with JDO+GAE and I'm having an issue when deleting a child in a owned one to one relationship. When I delete the child with `pm.deletePersistent(parent.getChild());` it is deleted from the data store correctly. However, its parent still has the reference to its already deleted child. I was expecting null but instead of that it has the reference. I don't know if that's how the thing works or if I'm missing something.

Comment: so you just delete the child without actually setting parent.setChild(null) ?!

Comment: of course I do. I just wanted to know if there's any way to change that behaviour so you don't have to set to null every child you delete.

Comment: parent will keep reference to child as long as you don't (un)set that reference. That applies to all ORM technologies in the Java world that I know of

Comment: the only proviso to that is where the relation is bidirectional, in which case the delete of the "child" will know about the parent and hence is able to cascade it or null the reference itself. But then you post no code so this is all guesswork

Comment: sorry about the delay Neil. I've been away of my proyect for a month and now that I come back it is like if I had forgotten things. Bidirectional it is the key, you are right. My relationship is not full bidirectional, I mean from the JDO's point of view. The parent has its child, however, the child has the key of its parent and not the object. I save it as `@Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.parent-pk", value="true")` , which probably confused me at the first sight and made me think that it was bidirectional. I think that's the thing. Thanks ;)